# Replace blob url and other strings in included html file using php

Tags: php, string, replace

i have 2 files . one is  **test.html** ,and other is **main.php**

**test.html**

```
<div class=\"col-sm-5 blind-s4\">
          <div class=\"blind-box \">
                <img src="blob:http://example.com/aea01f28-dcd0-41c2-80fa-4f021fe9d40d" class="new-img">
                </div>  
        </div>
```

Second in **main.php**

```
<div class="full-html" id="full-html">
            <?php include("test.html");?> 
    </div>
```

Here i want to replace all  `\"` in `test.html`  with   `"` .

(2) I want to replace all starting with blob with new image name

```
  ie:blob:http://example.com/aea01f28-dcd0-41c2-80fa-4f021fe9d40d with new.img
```

**or**

```
blob:http://example.com/some_url   with new.img
```

How i can do this ?

Comment: $string = str_replace( '\"', '"', $string );

Comment: What @halojoy means is `<?php str_replace( '\"', '"', include("test.html")); ?> `

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has changed from its original shape.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function replaceSlash($content) {
  return str_replace('\"', '"', $content);
}

ob_start('replaceSlash');
include('test.html');
ob_end_flush();
```

([Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487870/2056125))

Comment: Please check the question now

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_contents` and `str_replace`

like that

```
$myFile = file_get_contents('text.html');
$newFile = str_replace('\"', '"', $myFile);
```

And then you can write the content with echo

```
echo $newFile;
```

### **Update**

for replacing blob you should use regexp

```
str_replace(/src="blob:[^"]*/, 'src="new.img"', $newFile);
```