# how can i block the css of included page

Tags: php, html, css

I have two php page page1.php and page2.php
page1 have a another css and page2 have another css file linked.
now when i'm using the page 1 in page2 using `include("page1.php")`;
then the css file of page1 is interrupting the style of the page2 .
how can i resolove that.

Comment: Use unique styles/class names.

Comment: The fact you even have such a situation sounds like the result of a bigger design flaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a constant in `page2.php` and stop `page1.php` to add those CSS files using [`defined`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) to check if a constant is declared. This way, it will only be skipped if called via page2.php and not otherwise.

**page2.php:**

```
<?php

declare('BLOCK_PAGE_1_CSS',true); 

// rest of your code

include_once('page1.php);
```

**page1.php:**

```
<?php

if(!defined('BLOCK_PAGE_1_CSS')){
   // include those CSS files
}

// rest of your code
```

Comment: @Somnath Can you share a reproducible code? It is highly unlikely.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dl9p0Moz1FOpJCl3buKM04bqEK3-i1Ap?usp=sharing go to thgis link full code is there

Comment: include header in rating.php

Comment: @Somnath Which ones are page1.php and page2.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234525/discussion-between-somnath-and-nice-dev).

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't require changes to **page1.php** :

Let us assume page1.php has the below tag `link` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
```

Then, in **page2.php**, while including **page1.php**, you can do a **str_replace** on the buffered page1.php and output from the buffer.

```
<?php 
function callback($buffer)
    {
      return (str_replace('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">', '', $buffer));
    }
ob_start("callback");
include 'page1.php';
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Reference:

1. [Replace string from PHP include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487709/replace-string-from-php-include-file/18955869)